# How do I add a class to an li using a JQuery array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to write a script that when you click the a tags it will add the class 'menu-toc-current' to the relevant li elements. (Obviously remove this class when the next item is clicked). So click the link cats it adds the class to the li cats etc.

My code so far is ...

```
<ul id="menu-toc">
    <li>Cat</li>
    <li>Dog</li> 
    <li>Bird</li> 
</ul>

<a class="alive">Show me Cats</a>
<a class="alive">Show me Dogs</a>
<a class="alive">Show me Birds</a>
```

The JQuery I have so far is ...

```
$('a.alive').click( function(){
    $('ul#menu-toc').toggleClass('menu-toc-current');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a `data-` attribute to each link, referencing either the number of the `li` you wish to toggle or (better) an ID of that element.

```js
$('a.alive').click(function() {
  var elnum = $(this).data('elnum');
  $('ul#menu-toc li').removeClass('menu-toc-current')
        .eq(elnum).toggleClass('menu-toc-current');
});
```

```css
.menu-toc-current {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-toc">
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Dog</li>
  <li>Bird</li>
</ul>

<a href="javascript:" class="alive" data-elnum="0">Show me Cats</a>
<a href="javascript:" class="alive" data-elnum="1">Show me Dogs</a>
<a href="javascript:" class="alive" data-elnum="2">Show me Birds</a>
```

http://api.jquery.com/data

---

Using IDs instead of numbers is advantageous, however, because it makes it easier to rearrange the list:

```js
$('a.alive').click(function() {
  var elid = $(this).data('elid');
  $('ul#menu-toc li').removeClass('menu-toc-current')
        .filter('#'+elid).toggleClass('menu-toc-current');
});
```

```css
.menu-toc-current {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-toc">
  <li id="cat">Cat</li>
  <li id="dog">Dog</li>
  <li id="bird">Bird</li>
</ul>

<a href="javascript:" class="alive" data-elid="cat">Show me Cats</a>
<a href="javascript:" class="alive" data-elid="dog">Show me Dogs</a>
<a href="javascript:" class="alive" data-elid="bird">Show me Birds</a>
```

Now, if you want to move "Cat" after "Dog" later on, you don't need to change the `data-elid` attribute like you would `data-elnum`.

Comment: This is the clearest answer for me. It is almost there apart from it doesn't seem to remove the class if the next a is clicked. Could it do that?

Comment: you can do `$('ul#menu-toc li').removeClass('menu-toc-current');` in the first line of the .click function callback, to remove already selected option.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part in my haste. Added.

Comment: Still can't get it to remove the class :( Sorry

Comment: Are you seeing JavaScript errors in your console? The code snippets in my answer work fine. Perhaps you need to wrap your code in `$(document).ready` or move it to the bottom of the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you can do it with inline code like this:

```
<ul id="menu-toc">
    <li id="cat">Cat</li>
    <li id="dog">Dog</li> 
    <li id="bird">Bird</li> 
</ul>

<a class="alive" onclick="$('cat').toggleClass('menu-toc-current')">Show me Cats</a>
<a class="alive" onclick="$('dog').toggleClass('menu-toc-current')">Show me Dogss</a>
<a class="alive" onclick="$('bird').toggleClass('menu-toc-current')">Show me Birds</a>
```

It is good practive to separate code and markup. You can do that like this:

```
<ul id="menu-toc">
    <li id="cat">Cat</li>
    <li id="dog">Dog</li> 
    <li id="bird">Bird</li> 
</ul>

<a class="alive" id="cat-link">Show me Cats</a>
<a class="alive" id="dog-link">Show me Dogss</a>
<a class="alive" id="bird-link">Show me Birds</a>

<script>
    $("cat-link").click(function(){$('cat').toggleClass('menu-toc-current')});
    $("dog-link").click(function(){$('dog').toggleClass('menu-toc-current')});
    $("bird-link").click(function(){$('bird').toggleClass('menu-toc-current')});
</script>
```

If you have many links and do not want to reference each by an id like "cat" and "dog", you can do this:

```
<ul id="menu-toc">
    <li id="cat" data-index="1">Cat</li>
    <li id="dog" data-index="2">Dog</li> 
    <li id="bird" data-index="3">Bird</li> 
</ul>

<a class="alive animal-link" data-index="1">Show me Cats</a>
<a class="alive animal-link" data-index="2">Show me Dogss</a>
<a class="alive animal-link" data-index="3">Show me Birds</a>

<script>
    $(".animal-link").click(function(){
        $("#menu-toc").find("[data-index='" + $(this).attr("data-index")+ "']").toggleClass("menu-toc-current");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: While this works, inline `onclick` attributes are generally discouraged because they run against the principle of [separation of  concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns?oldformat=true#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_JavaScript).

Comment: @Blazemonger good point, I have update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I didn't wish to give ids to the id's. Wnated to try and learn the harder way :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {

     $(".alive").click(function(){      
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("ul#menu-toc li").removeClass('red');
        $("#" + id + "-li").addClass('red');
     });
     
});
```

```css
.red {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-toc">
    <li id="cats-li">Cat</li>
    <li id="dogs-li">Dog</li> 
    <li id="birds-li">Bird</li> 
</ul>

<a class="alive" id="cats" href="#">Show me Cats</a>
<a class="alive" id="dogs" href="#">Show me Dogss</a>
<a class="alive" id="birds" href="#">Show me Birds</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, I have about 20 links so I want to write a more DRY solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to do an accordion menu: http://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/mcgv4gok/

```
<nav>
    <div id="navContainer">
        <ul>
            <li>
            <a href='' class='tabButton' data-openTab='1'>1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href='' class='tabButton' data-openTab='2'>2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href='' class='tabButton' data-openTab='3'>3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href='' class='tabButton' data-openTab='4'>4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href='' class='tabButton' data-openTab='5'>5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id = "tabCont" class="tabContainer">
        <div id="1">1
            <a href="" class="closeButton"> CLOSE </a>
        </div>
        <div id="2" >2
            <a href="" class="closeButton"> CLOSE </a>
        </div>
        <div id="3" > 3
            <a href="" class="closeButton"> CLOSE </a>
        </div>
        <div id="4" >  4
            <a href="" class="closeButton"> CLOSE </a>
        </div>
        <div id="5" >   5
            <a href="" class="closeButton"> CLOSE </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

    document.menuIsOpen = false;
    $('.tabContainer > div').hide();
    $('.tabButton').click(function(event) {
        var
            open = $("#" + $(this).attr('data-openTab')),
            isOpened = open.is('.opened');

        event.preventDefault();
        if (document.menuIsOpen) {
            document.menuIsOpen = false;
            $('.opened').hide("slow").removeClass('opened');
        }
        if (!isOpened) {
            document.menuIsOpen = true;
            open.addClass('opened').show("slow").css("display", "block");
        }
    });
    $('.closeButton').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.opened').hide("slow").removeClass('opened');
    });
    $('.tabContainer > div').hide();
```

Comment: On what are you basing this assumption?

Comment: On the fact that he wants to mark/unmark elements based on clicking on links - which is accordion menu (even when not used as menu!).

Comment: Your answer is overly complex, and in no way directly answers the question OP actually asked. Nor does it incorporate any of OP's actual code. The mission of StackOverflow is to provide answers to questions for posterity so that other people can use them to solve similar problems. For this reason, you should only rely on the information that OP provided.